# Ansible Composer Module Missing?

Tags: composer-php, ansible

When I try to use the [Ansible's Composer module](http://docs.ansible.com/composer_module.html) and paste the following task into my playbook.yml file I get an error.

**playbook.yml**

```
- name: Composer Install Site Dependencies
  composer: command=install working_dir=/var/www/html
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR: composer is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

After some investigation I ran "anisble-doc --list" on the command line to see the available modules and "composer" is not listed. I am running Ansible version 1.5.4, do I have to add it separately?

Comment: Err, the [module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/composer_module.html) says _new in version 1.6_. Can you simply upgrade your Ansible installation ?

Comment: @user272735 OOh yeah that was a bit of an over site. But the strange thing is I think they are only up to version 1.5.5 unless I have missed something else https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases

Comment: right @TheoKouzelis, they haven't released it yet. You can patch/add it locally. Hmm. I'll expand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user272735 indicated in the comments, this is an unreleased module- it's slated for the 1.6 release, [which is under "active development"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/89fa9b73059becbba164da88faa10a9fe746f366/CHANGELOG.md). (admittedly it was [originally slated for 1.4](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/f700da82490ad91778068414be7f575416d98336#diff-29fa9a4412142800de5ada740efc2edc)) You have a couple of options:

- install ansible from the bleeding edge. See "[running from source](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#running-from-source)". (obviously, this is scary)
- ninja-patch [the file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/library/packaging/composer) into your locally installed tree. (obviously, this is scary)
- add [the file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/library/packaging/composer) into your local Ansible repo.

As "[developing modules](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html)" says, a fourth option is to specify your library path via `ANSIBLE_LIBRARY` or `--module-path`. HOWEVER, this overrides your global library/module path. That isn't what you want to do unless you are providing every module.

### adding into your repo

I'm assuming your repo is named "ansible" and is [set up properly](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout), like this:

`ansible/
ansible/roles/
ansible/group_vars/`

In that case, simply add a `library` directory at the top (the 'best practices' discusses this but not in the expected section):

`ansible/
ansible/roles/
ansible/group_vars/
ansible/library/`

Inside there, add [the `composer` file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/library/packaging/composer) in there. That makes its path/file the following:

```
ansible/library/composer
```

Note it is not `composer.py` or anything else. Also, it doesn't seem to need the `+x` bit, so no fussy worries there.

Once you do that, you can run Ansible commands as you'd expect. The composer module will simply be there.